# no of times picklist values recurring in related list salesforce trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

I am trying to get no of times a field value recurred in a related list.Can anyone let me know how to achieve this. I have statred wrting the below trigger.

Parent Object Work_Order__c
Child - Work_Order_Item__c

```
trigger WOServiceTrigger on Work_Order_Item__c (after insert, after update, after delete) {

    Set<Id> ids = new Set<Id>();
    List<Work_Order__c> wo = new List<Work_Order__c>();
    List<Work_Order_Item__c> woi1 = new List<Work_Order_Item__c>();
    List<Account> acc = new List<Account>();

    Map<String, Integer> parentToHighest = new Map<String, Integer>();
    Map<String, String> parentToValue = new Map<String, String>();

    for(Work_Order_Item__c woi:trigger.new){

        ids.add(woi.Work_Order__c);
    }

    woi1=[select id,Work_Order__c,Work_Order__r.Account__c,Service__c from Work_Order_Item__c where Work_Order__c=:ids];

    for(AggregateResult ar:[select count(Id) num, Service__c, Work_Order__c from Work_Order_Item__c where Work_Order__c in : ids group by Work_Order__c, Service__c]){

        Integer num = (Integer)ar.get('num');
        system.debug('@@@@@num'+num);
        String name = (String)ar.get('Work_Order__c');
        system.debug('@@@@@num'+name);
        String type = (String)ar.get('Service__c');
        system.debug('@@@@@num'+type);


        if(parentToHighest.get(type) == null || parentToHighest.get(type) < num)
    {
        parentToHighest.put(type, num);
        parentToValue.put(type, type);
    }

    }


}
```

Comment: so, what is the issue?  [edit] your post to show what debug is showing. Is it what you expect?

Comment: Service__c is a picklist field . I want to know how many times each value in the picklist have been used.

Comment: Is that per `Work_order__c` record, or in total, or just those records in your Set?  I'm assuming a report doesn't meet the business need?